# Trying to get object id with date in pymongo

Tags: pymongo

```
import pymongo
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from time import gmtime, strftime 

gen_time = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(gen_time)
result = db["config"].find({"_id":{"$lt": dummy_id}})
print(result)
```

and its showing erorr AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Comment: For future reference, it would have been better if you'd told us which line was giving you the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string to [`ObjectId.from_datetime()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/1.5.2/api/pymongo/objectid.html):

```
gen_time = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(gen_time)
```

whereas the docs say

> Pass either a naive datetime instance containing UTC, or an aware instance that has been converted to UTC.

You probably want

```
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(datetime.utcnow())
```

(or maybe `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` since you're just doing `import datetime`)